# Vertical align of two md column with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've searched and tried all Stackoverflow solutions without success.

I've this code and I'm using bootstrap3

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="Images/social/facebook.png" alt="facebook" class="footerimg" /></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="Images/social/twitter.png" alt="twitter" class="footerimg" /></a>
              <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="Images/social/youtube.png" alt="youtube" class="footerimg" /></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <p class="text-right">&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> Test - All Rights Reserved</p><p class="text-right">P.IVA 123456789</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I would like to vertically center `col-md-4` elements and I have footer styles like this:

```
footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 120px;
}
```

I've already tried with table-cell applied to `col-md-4` but without success.

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: have you tried adding `!important` rule to `display: table` like so `display:table !important;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something like this : (images are not shown)

[image]

I made a **[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/987/)**.

This is the code :

```
 <footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
              <div class="centered">
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="Images/social/facebook.png" alt="facebook" class="footerimg" /></a>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="Images/social/twitter.png" alt="twitter" class="footerimg" /></a>
                  <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="Images/social/youtube.png" alt="youtube" class="footerimg" /></a>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-4">
              <div class="centered">
                  <p class="text-right">&copy; Test - All Rights Reserved</p><p class="text-right">P.IVA 123456789</p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And the **CSS**

```
footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 120px;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.centered {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   height: 120px;
}
```

Ref : [centering-in-the-unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)